# Is there a way to use automator/write an apple script to change the font in several powerpoint documents?

Tags: applescript, ms-office, automator, font

A recurring issue at work:

A powerpoint file needs to be moved in to illustrator and saved as an .eps file. The files are almost always submitted with the font set to Calibri which Illustrator doesn't like for whatever reason. I select all the type and change it to Univers which usually enters Illustrator quite well. I'm looking for a way to speed up this process. I'd like to be able to put all my .ppt files in a folder, select that folder, have all the documents open, the type selected and changed to univers (Univers LT Std 55), then have the file save and close. Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: It is possible. Did you try it ?

Comment: Hi Buscar, I'm afraid I don't know how. I've looked at the actions available in automator and have tried to record an action but haven't been able to get it to work. The only programs I really know how to create actions for are photoshop and illustrator.

Answer (score 1):

***Short answer:***

Yes, it's possible. You just need to use the `Record` button in Automator to record your own mouse movements as you change the font in one PowerPoint file. Then save this recording as a Folder Action. Now every time you drop a some files into a folder with this action, it will automatically run at your mouse movements on those files.

I'm including a screenshot of a proof-of-concept Folder Action that I made just now, but in all honesty, this will probably take a lot of tinkering around and may not be a very clean way to do it.

***Better answer:***

**There is a better way to do this** but it will only work on the new `.pptx` format presentations, not on any of the old `.ppt` files.

Basically, all you have to do is rename your powerpoint as `.zip` and then unzip it like a folder.

Once you open the folder, navigate to:

```
ppt > slides > slide#.xml
```

Where the "#" is slide number you want to edit. In my case, I only have `slide1.xml` but you will probably have others too.

Once you open the xml it should be pretty straightforward to search the xml text for the word Calibri and replace it with the words Univers LT.

That's it :)

All you have to do now is save the xml, zip the folder again, and rename the zipped file back to `.pptx`.

This may sound tedious to do, but I'm sure it's possible to write a simple 5-10 line bash script that will do exactly this. Unfortunately, I can't do it tonight so perhaps one of the mods can help out and post a script for me.

If I have some time tomorrow, I'll try to write one for you and test it on my computer. :)

*Screenshots:*

[image]

Comment: Hi Vladimir, Many thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately, I cannot get them to work properly. I have several pptx files for the project I'm working on and I tried what you suggested- zipping the files and opening the xml file in a text editor. When I search for 'calibri' it isn't found even though Calibri IS being used as the font in the file. Please see my screenshot here http://i.imgur.com/hmCJ0Sm.png. Please let me know if you have any more advice. thanks

Comment: @sean Oh!!! I'm so sorry! I completely forgot to get back to you on this. If possible (i.e. there is no sensitive information in them), could you put one of the ppt files on dropbox so that I may take a look and write a script that will work for you particular files?

Comment: Hi Vladimir, No need to apologize- I really appreciate your desire to help. Sorry it took me a few days to get back to you. I've added two powerpoint files to Dropbox. I can add more if it will help in any way. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1n72c8wf10yvh4c/AADJDUbPcxXy5-0N9TX0FG1Aa?dl=0

Comment: @sean I found Calibri in `/ppt/theme/theme1.xml`. I assume that this is just where they store the default slide formats. Special formats should still show up in the place I described earlier. But I've ran into a problem... It seems that unlike Word files, PowerPoint doesn't like the zip operation on a Mac. So this makes writing a script problematic because we will need to use a third party program to rezip the files. See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706469/error-in-the-following-process-unzip-pptx-modify-content-rezip-to-pptx) for details on zipping pptx files.